# Test if a function uses another function

Tags: r

Is there a way to determine if a function calls another function? For example, I would like to know if a user-created function (lets say `f()`) uses a function (example `sum()`).

```r
f <- function(x, y) {
  sum(x, y)
}

# test_if_f_uses_sum(f)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>